# How to pass object name value pair as a parameter to the method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of object that returns the following data:

```
result [
  {name: "Desc", value: "7777 - Florida Hurricane"}
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7777"}
  {name: "Desc", value: "7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)"}
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7172"}
  {name: "Desc", value: "7002 - Maryland Hurricane"}
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7002"}
]
```

I need to pass in the disaster number as a parameter to my `getProcessList()` method to fetch the process list by the disaster number once the response is successful.

```
if (response.type == API_DISASTER_BY_ID_GET_SUCCESS) {
  this.getProcessList();
}
```

Based on the response output above, how can I properly pass the "`DSTR_NR`" (disaster number) to my method?

**UPDATE**

Whichever disaster I choose from the disaster dropdown, only that disaster value needs to pass to the `getProcessList()` method so that the corresponding list of process can be fetch for the process dropdown.
[image]

```
<Dropdown
  placeholder={placeholder}
  search
  selection
  clearable
  options={options}
  value={this.state.value}
  style={style}
  onChange={(e, d) => {
    let result = d.options.filter(d => d.value === 'DSTR_NR');
    console.log(result)
    this.setState({ value: result });
    this.props.saveReduxData(datapath, result);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: You could filter the "DSTR_NR" objects from the array and then pass those values into your method. Do you only need to pass the `value` associated with a "DSTR_NR" to your method or the entire object with `name` and `value` keys?

Comment: @TannerDolby thanks for the response. I only need to pass the "value" associated with a DSTR_NR to the method. Can you show me an example of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the array of objects from the response using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Then you can pass the values from those "DSTR_NR" objects to your method. If you want to only have the values from each `value` key in the filtered array of objects, just use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let result = [
  {name: "Desc", value: "7777 - Florida Hurricane"},
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7777"},
  {name: "Desc", value: "7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)"},
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7172"},
  {name: "Desc", value: "7002 - Maryland Hurricane"},
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7002"}
];

// array of "DSTR_NR" key-value pairs
let disasterVals = result.filter(i => i.name === "DSTR_NR");
console.log(disasterVals);

// array of `value`'s
let values = disasterVals.map(i => i.value);
console.log(values);

function someMethod(val) {
  return "Disaster Val: " + val;
}

// access value from array of objects
console.log(someMethod(disasterVals[0].value));

// or access value from array of `value`'s
console.log(someMethod(values[1]));
console.log(someMethod(values[2]));
```

Comment: This is great, Tanner. Thank you so much. It does what I was looking for. However there's one issue that I see. It passes all the DSTR_NR values in an array. The page that I have contains a dropdown which renders that result data that I mentioned in my post. On the click of the desired value that I choose from the dropdown, only that value which is associated with DSTR_NR needs to be pass on to the method.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand correctly, you have a list `<options>` let's say, which represent an object with the associated "DSTR_NR" and "value" keys when you click a dropdown item? Or are the `name: "Desc"` objects also clickable from the dropdown list? What you want is to pass the `value` of the item you clicked from the dropdown menu.

Comment: yes, that is correct. You are on the right track. I have a list of options that represents an object with DSTR_NR and value key. The name: "Desc" object is also clickable from the dropdown list but at the end all I need to pass is the value that is associated with DSTR_NR because that's what the second rest call expects to return me a list of process corresponding to the disaster number that I select.

Comment: I've updated my post. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @Shaun Ok thanks for clarifying, let me spin something up. What does the `event` output from the `onChange` event when you console.log it with `console.log(e.target.value)` will that represent the object you clicked in the dropdown?

Comment: That returned me the html element `<div role="option" aria-checked="true" aria-selected="true" class="active selected item" style="pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">7777 - Florida Hurricane </span></div>`

Comment: @Shaun Ok we're getting somewhere. That has the value in it's `innerHTML` corresponding to the `DSTR_NR` object. Since your not using `<option>` elements for the dropdown with `value` attributes. It makes this a bit more difficult. If you used `<option>` elements instead of `<div>`'s, you could put the `value="1"` etc which then if the options correspond to the order of the array of objects, you could just grab the object at the array index ie if you clicked the `<option>` with value="0" it would allow to get the array value at index 0, ie `{ key: "DSTR_NR", text: "7777" }`.

Comment: @Shaun If you put your code for the dropdown into a [CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/) or StackBlitz, I'm happy to have a look and provide a fix, I can't seem to wrap my head around all the moving pieces just from the Component and screenshot.

Comment: thanks for all the help. I tried to create a sandbox but was not able to...but the good news is I was able to solve my issue.

Comment: @Shaun Your welcome. I'm glad you were able to solve your issue. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

the result is an array and there are multiple `"DSTR_NR"` so there will be multiple values that can be passed as the parameters

you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

example:

```js
result = [
  {name: "Desc", value: "7777 - Florida Hurricane"}
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7777"}
  {name: "Desc", value: "7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)"}
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7172"}
  {name: "Desc", value: "7002 - Maryland Hurricane"}
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7002"}
]

// the filtered result will be
filteredResult = result.filter(d => d.name === 'DSTR_NR');

// the filtered result will be 
/*
[ 
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7777"},
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7172"},
  {name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7002"},
]

*/
```

to get just the numbers you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) on the filtered result

```js
onlyNumbers =  filteredResult.map(d => d.value);

/*
 output:- 
    ["7777", "7172", "7002"]
*/
```

in one liner:

```js
result.filter(d => d.name === 'DSTR_NR').map(d => d.value);

/*
    output:- 
    ["7777", "7172", "7002"]
*/
```

the output can be simply passed as an array as a single parameter or you can use a spread operator to send multiple parameters based on the output.

```js
output = ["7777", "7172", "7002"];

// as a single paramater (array)
myFync(output);

// as multiple paramaters
myFunc(...output);
```

Comment: Saurabh, thank you so much for your response with all the explanation. It does what I was looking for. However there's one issue that I see. It passes all the DSTR_NR values in an array. The page that I have contains a dropdown which renders that result data that I mentioned in my post. On the click of the desired value that I choose from the dropdown, only that value which is associated with DSTR_NR needs to be pass on to the method

Comment: can you share what's the output you are expecting?

Comment: I've updated my post. Let me know if you need more info.